# The Dirac matrices are to 3+1D what "those matrices" are to 4D - What are "those matrices"?

Tags: matrices, euclidean-geometry

The Dirac matrix have the following properties

$$
\gamma_\mu\gamma_\nu = \eta_{\mu\nu}\\
$$

This works in 3+1D because the signature is $(+,-,-,-)$.

They can be used to represent a vector in 3+1D like this $v = t\gamma_0+ x\gamma_1+y\gamma_2+z\gamma_3$.

---

In 3D, we have the Pauli matrices

$$
\sigma_i\sigma_j = \delta_{ij}
$$

One can write a vector in 3D like this $v=x\gamma_x+y\gamma_y+z\gamma_z$.

---

I am looking for 4x4 matrices which works for signature $(+,+,+,+)$. The properties would be

$$
\mathbf{\hat{x}}_i \mathbf{\hat{x}}_j= \delta_{ij}
$$

The matrices would be 4x4 and would allow one to write a vector $v=x \mathbf{\hat{x}} + y \mathbf{\hat{y}} + z \mathbf{\hat{z}} + w\mathbf{\hat{w}}$

Are these matrices known? I would like to know the entries of those matrices.

Comment: Have you tried $i\gamma_0,\gamma_1,\gamma_2,\gamma_3$ ? This idea is from Wick rotation.

Comment: @KurtG. That is a good idea, but I was hoping that the matrices form the generator of a basis of 4x4 real matrices. I wish to define bivectors, pseudovectors and the pseudoscalar as products of those matrices, while keeping a representation in the real 4x4 matrices. Just like $\sigma_1$ and $sigma_2$ (and $\sigma_1\sigma_2$) form a representation of 2x2 matrices $a+x\sigma_x+y\sigma_y + b \sigma_x\sigma_y$

Comment: The [Dirac matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices) as I know them are not real. Neither are the Pauli matrices as we know. This has not stopped people to use them as basis for real vector spaces. You must distinguish between the matrix algebra and the coefficients (real or complex) you apply to them.

Comment: @KurtG. It works in 2D with the real with $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ (and $\sigma_1\sigma_2$). It forms a representation of 2x2 matrices $a+x\sigma_x+y\sigma_y + b \sigma_x\sigma_y$. And this is isomorphic to the geometric algebra of 2 dimensions.

Comment: I totally believe that. Let's see what other commenters deliver. This business is different in every dimension which makes it so interesting.